# Reading opencv_core.Mat from opencv_core.FileStorage in Java

Tags: java, xml, opencv

like in topic, I don't know how to read data from my .xml file. I have already wrote data into XML file using FileStorage class (used opencv_core.write method) but now I want to read these data into two Mat's (data are divided with two tags - "TrainingData" and "TrainingLabels").

Here is the code:

```
opencv_core.FileStorage fs = new opencv_core.FileStorage("SVM.xml", opencv_core.FileStorage.READ);

opencv_core.Mat SVM_TrainingData = new opencv_core.Mat();
opencv_core.Mat SVM_Classes = new opencv_core.Mat();

opencv_core.FileNode dataNode = new FileNode();
opencv_core.FileNode labelsNode = new FileNode();
dataNode = fs.get("TrainingData");
labelsNode = fs.get("TrainingLabels");


opencv_core.read(dataNode, SVM_TrainingData);
opencv_core.read(labelsNode, SVM_Classes);
```

But these Mat's are empty ones after this... And I don't know how to solve that.

XML looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<TrainingData type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>151</rows>
<cols>4752</cols>
<dt>u</dt>
<data>
0 0 28 58 64 62 57 45 37 37 48 61 64 65 66 64 65 67 65 62 61 61 60
61 59 60 58 60 58 54 56 56 53 51 47 51 48 47 43 45 43 43 42 40 39 38
...
219 232 234 239 238 233 173 121 91 38 19 19 21</data></TrainingData>
<TrainingLabels type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>151</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>i</dt>
<data>
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</data></TrainingLabels>
</opencv_storage>
```

Any help in reading these data into two Mat's would be great!